# How to create a list of namedtuples from a generator object?

Tags: python

This script uses Python 3.7.4. I am trying to understand more about how to use generators and namedtuples. Here is the sample data.txt I am using.

```
timestamp,systolic,diastolic,pulse
201711051037,135,81,62
201711061614,121,74,60
201711150922,129,74,70
201711170901,135,80,65
201803221638,119,80,72
```

I would like to create a generator object, then use the generator object to create a list of namedtupels, something like this.

```
[BP(timestamp=201711051037, systolic=135, diastolic=81, pulse=62),
...
BP(timestamp=201803221638, systolic=119, diastolic=80, pulse=72)]
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def fetch_reading(source):
    try:
        with open(source, 'r') as txtfile:
            for line in txtfile:
                yield line.strip().split(',')
    except TypeError:
        pass

def create_namedtuple_list(source):
    container = list()
    #  FIXME
    return container
```

The fetch_reading() function works as expected.

```
>>> gen = fetch_reading('data.txt')
>>> type(gen)
<class 'generator'>
>>> next(gen)
['timestamp', 'systolic', 'diastolic', 'pulse']
>>> next(gen)
['201711051037', '135', '81', '62']
```

I am stuck on the create_namedtuple_list() function (the part where we use the generator object to create a list of namedtuples). Any hints or links to the right resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "does not work" is not terribly useful.

Comment: What does "does not work" precisely mean? Does it throw an error? What error? Please post the traceback. Or is it something else? Please be more precise, and give an accurate description of the problem.

Comment: You should not be using `_make` method. The prefixing `_` indicates that this is not for public use. You should be simply mapping with `BP`. Also, notice how your `gen_obj` only ouptuts a string, not your three elements. Therefore, `BP` is going to read it as a single argument and not 3.

Comment: @awakenedhaki Not in this case. `namedtuple._make` is public and [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make) API, the leading underscore is not there to signal private or internal use but to avoid name clashing.

Comment: I re-worded the question and removed the '_' from the code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with, hopefully it will be of use to someone.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def fetch_reading(source):
    try:
        with open(source, 'r') as txtfile:
            for line in txtfile:
                yield line.strip().split(',')
    except TypeError:
        pass

def create_namedtuple_list(source):
    container = list()
    gen = fetch_reading(source)  # generator object
    nt = namedtuple('BP', next(gen))
    while gen:
        try:
            container.append(nt(*next(gen)))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    return container
```

This returns a list of namedtuples as expected.

```
>>> bp_read = create_namedtuple_list('data.txt')
>>> type(bp_read)
<class 'list'>
>>> bp_read[0]
BP(timestamp='201711051037', systolic='135', diastolic='81', pulse='62')
>>> bp_read[1]
BP(timestamp='201711061614', systolic='121', diastolic='74', pulse='60')
>>> bp_read[0].timestamp
'201711051037'
```

You can also use the namedtupel methods.

```
>>> bp_read[0]._fields
('timestamp', 'systolic', 'diastolic', 'pulse')
```

You can read about namedtuples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `_` incorrectly. The underscore is used to indicate a variable you will not use/don't care about. Since you are actually using it in your loops, you should provide it with a proper name, such as `line`.

It is more common to initiate lists using the literal `data = []`, rather than `list()`.

You may want to look into `csv` and `pathlib` modules. I refactored your code to work with `pathlib`, provides an OOP approach to `os.path`.

```
import csv

from pathlib import Path
from collections import namedtuple

class GenerateBPData(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = Path(source)

    @property
    def rows(self):
        row = namedtuple('BP', self.header)
        with self.source.open('r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                yield row(*line)

    @property
    def header(self):
        with self.source.open('r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
        return next(reader)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and the heads-up. I will check that out.

Comment: I found an interesting article at the website DataCamp on the 'Role of Underscore(_) in Python' 
at https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/role-underscore-python, that was helpful for me.

Comment: They are using `_` in a way that is not entirely wise. You should always provide semantically meaningful variable names, that way people can understand your code. I wasn't sure that your `_` meant in your code, so I had to run it to check. This is a disadvantage in the future, since people should not have to run code in order to know what a variable means.